# Show/Hide Div based on $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using a Bootstrap 3 Alert `div` to flash a message when a transaction is completed. The Alert contents is coming from a header (location) from the previous page.

Above the closing /body tag:

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 4000);
</script>
```

And my Alert:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert" style="font-size:120%;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>

    <?php

        $email = $_GET['e'];
        $receipt = $_GET['r'];

    if (isset($_GET["msg"])) {

        $msg = $_GET["msg"];

        if ($msg == "1") {

            echo "Receipt $receipt was sent to $email.";
        } else {

            echo "Message was not sent.";
        }
    }
    ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

The Alert `div` shows up even if the `$_GET`'s are not there. In other words on load before I do anything the `div` is there blank. I want the user to complete the form on my page and be redirected with the URL?msg=1 to same page with the Alert message showing. Other than that the `div` does not have to show.

Comment: Maybe you can try getting some more JS involved, instead of adding an HTML tag, add Javascript script or parameters for JS.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the alert code inside a PHP if statement where you can check if the $_GET variable are set.

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['r'])) { ?>

   <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert" style="font-size:120%;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>

        <?php

            $email = $_GET['e'];
            $receipt = $_GET['r'];

        if (isset($_GET["msg"])) {

            $msg = $_GET["msg"];

            if ($msg == "1") {

                echo "Receipt $receipt was sent to $email.";
            } else {

                echo "Message was not sent.";
            }
        }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your solution was perfect. Many thanks Kld. I appreciate your prompt assistance.